# How to get user profile information from facebook account kit?

Tags: image, location, profile

I have logged into Facebook through accountkit.

How do I get user profile information(`username,profile image`), if the phone number or email user address entered is already registered with Facebook?

Answer (score 5):

Facebook and Account Kit accounts are separate products and you cannot log in to Facebook via Account Kit. When somebody logs in via Account Kit you'll only have access to their phone number or email.

If you'd like profile pictures, public profile, etc you should use Facebook Login.